# asound.conf file is corrupted does not allow the play with the correct sound card as a result it keeps failing

Tags: ubuntu, fedora, audio, alsa, pulseaudio

I have this following asound.conf file, but when i play $ speaker-test it fails. How can you tell asound.conf that each and every time on restart of pc also use this sound card only?

```
"card 2: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC892 Analog [ALC892 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1"??


$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
ALSA lib conf.c:1220:(parse_def) default is not a compound
ALSA lib conf.c:1686:(snd_config_load1) _toplevel_:2:13:Invalid argument
ALSA lib conf.c:3406:(config_file_open) /etc/asound.conf may be old or corrupted: consider to remove or fix it
card 1: Device [C-Media USB Audio Device], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC892 Analog [ALC892 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 1: ALC892 Digital [ALC892 Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

$ cat /etc/asound.conf
    pcm.default {
        type hw # Kernel PCM
        card 2
        device 0 # Device number (default 0)
        #[subdevice] INT # Subdevice number, -1 first available (default -1)
        #mmap_emulation BOOL # enable mmap emulation for ro/wo devices

    }
    pcm.!default {
        type hw # Kernel PCM
        card 2
        device 0 # Device number (default 0)
        #[subdevice] INT # Subdevice number, -1 first available (default -1)
        #mmap_emulation BOOL # enable mmap emulation for ro/wo devices
    }
```

I tried this it works but how to avoid using the hw:2,0 but use some static string so that on reboot it does not get lost?

```
pcm.!default {
         type asym
         playback.pcm {
                 type plug
                 slave.pcm "hw:0,1"
         }
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To just change the default cards, replace that `asound.conf` with this:

```
defaults.pcm.card 2
defaults.pcm.device 0
```

To be independent from changing card numbers, use the card ID instead:

```
defaults.pcm.card PCH
defaults.pcm.device 0
```